# Can I get django-oscar to work under Python 3?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-apps, django-oscar

I am working with Python 3.6.0, Django 1.10.6, and Oscar version 1.4.0 final.

I've seen similar-looking error messages discussed and reported solved by certain solutions (e.g. updating what was "still" an old-time autogenerated wsgi.py), or adding `import django` and `django.setup()` almost near the top (i.e. before `SECRET_KEY` and `INSTALLED_APPS`, moved up near the top). I've found closer matches to the error message on Github, where for the purposes of Raven people have been given the all-clear to delete standard user or authentication modules from their project. However, I have not found a place where someone reports the error and there is a solution other than an all-clear to delete a standard Django app from an unrelated Django-based project.

The specific error message and trace does not shout out to me what line is at issue beyond suspicions it is being triggered by inclusion of 'django.contrib.contenttypes' in INSTALLED_APPS. The trace I get when I try to run it is:

```
(store-env) ~/store $ python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 342, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/christos/store/store/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from oscar.app import application
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oscar/app.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/forms.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 138, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/Users/christos/store-env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 113, in __new__
    "INSTALLED_APPS." % (module, name)
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
(store-env) ~/store $
```

My current `settings.py`, helpfully or unhelpfully modified from what reportedly worked for others on SO, is, up to an untouched `import os`:

```
from oscar.defaults import *

from django.conf import settings

settings.configure()

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '[DELETED]'

from oscar import get_core_apps

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
    'django.contrib.sites.models.Site',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType',
    'compressor',
    'widget_tweaks'
] + get_core_apps()

import django
django.setup()
"""
Django settings for store project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.6.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os
```

What can/should I do that Oscar has all the apps that it should be getting?

Comment: You should be adding the app to installed apps not model i.e `django.contrib.sites` and `django.contrib.contenttypes`.

Comment: Thank you; I've deleted the lines referring to individual models. The error message is the same.

Comment: I see that my question has been downvoted. Could I have any advice as to what changes would make my question better and less downvote-worthy?

Answer (score 0):

```
'django.contrib.sites.models.Site',
'django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType'
```

This should not be in the installed apps section. These are models and the installed apps section is mainly for apps.